# Onclick image show div

Tags: html, css, image, onclick

I'm trying to hide a section of the page until a button is clicked, whats the best way to achieve this?

I have attached an image below encircled in red is the button I want to work as a toggle to show the content of the laptops section. Currently  if you click the image it just opens a tab with an image and instead I want it to show open the laptops and mac section.

I have attached a JS fiddle with my current code.

https://jsfiddle.net/2j4b4bdn/2/

[image]

```
  <html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">


    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <style>
   body {
        background-color: #161A25;
        margin:0;
    }
    #logo {
        position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    }
    h9
    {
      color: white;
        position:absolute;
    right:50rem;
    top:4rem;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }
       h10
    {
      color: white;
        position:absolute;
    right:30rem;
    top:4rem;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }
    h6
    {
      color: black;
        position:absolute;


        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }
    h7
    {
      color: #32CE87;
        position:absolute;
    right:6rem;
    top:2.5rem;
        font-size: 9px;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }

    h8
    {
      color: white;
        position:absolute;
    right:6rem;
    top:3.5rem;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        font-size: 22px;
       color: #32CE87;
    }

    .footer {
       position: fixed;
        right:0;
       bottom: 0;
       width: 100%;
        height:110px;
       background-color: #2A3046;
       color: white;


    }

    img.logo {
       height: 80px;
         left:3em;
        position: relative

    }
    img.logo1 {
       height: 40px;
        left:3em;

        bottom:2rem;
        position:absolute;
    }



    .my-button {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 1px;
        background: #32CE87;
        color: white;

        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        width: 100px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .my-button:hover {
        background: #666;
        color: #c1e1e0;
    }
    .center-bottom {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 12rem;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    img.arrow {
        max-height: 40px;
    }

    .row {
           background-color: white;
        max-width:100%;


        margin-top: 0.5rem;
        margin-left: 10px;
         margin-right: 10px;
         border-radius: 5px;

    }
    .box1 {
        background-color: white;
        max-width:100%;
        height:250px;
        padding-bottom:50px;
        margin-top: 0.5rem;
        margin-left: 25px;
        margin-right: 25px;
         border-radius: 5px;


    }

       img {
           margin-top:0.5rem;
       }

     div.container1 {
        background-color: white;
        max-width:100%;
        height:250px;
        padding-bottom:50px;
        margin-top: 0.5rem;
        margin-left: 25px;
        margin-right: 25px;
         border-radius: 5px;


    }



       div.container {
           margin-top:14rem;
       }
    p {
        font-size:7px;
        width:490px;
        position: absolute;
        right:12em;
        text-align: left;
        bottom: 1.5rem;

    }
    img.laptop { 

        height: 80px;
        position: absolute;
        left:0px;
        right: 0px;
        margin-top: -0.5rem;



        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto; 
    }
    div.bottomtext {
        position: relative;
         left:0px;
        right: 0px;
            font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto; 
        text-align: center;
     width:800px;
        top:7rem;
        font-size: 1.2rem;



    }

    img.textimage
    {
        height:20px;
        left:8rem;
        position: absolute;
         font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }

    .images {
        display: inline;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width:200px;
    }
    #content {
        display: block;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
        top: 90px;
        height: auto;
        max-width: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        overflow-x:auto;
        word-wrap:normal;
        white-space:nowrap;
        height: 50px;
    }

    img.column {
        height:50px;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    img.row
    {height:60px;

    }
    h9:hover {
          color: #32CE87;
    }
    h10:hover {
          color: #32CE87;

    }
    p:hover {
          color: #32CE87;

    }
    h7:hover {
          color: white;

    }
    h8:hover {
          color: white;

    }
     .pt-inner-wrap {
        color: #ecf0f1;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
        border-right: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
         bottom:-6px;

        }

       .pt-inner-wrap1 {
        color: #ecf0f1;
        height: 200px;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
        border-right: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
        bottom:-6px;
        }

       img.img-responsive {
           width: 230px;
           height: 32px;

       }

          img.img-responsive1 {
           width: 260px;
           height: 50px;
              margin-top: 12rem;

       }
       h4 {
           font-size: 18px;
         font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
           top: 1rem;
       }

       h6.pt-title {

           font-size: 20px;
       text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;

           position: absolute;


       }
         h6.pt-title1 {
           margin-top:8rem;
           font-size: 20px;
           width: 200px;
          margin-left:12rem;
           position: absolute


       }

       figcaption {
             font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
       }

       .col-xs-2{
    background: #32CE87;;
    color:#FFF;
           border-radius: 5px;
           height: 50px;
           text-align: center;
            padding-top: 5px;

           font-size: 3rem;
}
.col-half-offset{
    margin-left:4.166666667%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
     padding-top: 5px;


}

       p.text1 {
           position:fixed;
          bottom:23rem; 
          text-align:center; 
           width:160px;
           font-size:16px;
            font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
           right:86rem;
           border-right: 1px solid;
       }
           p.text2 {
           position:fixed;
          bottom:23rem; 
          text-align:center; 
           width:160px;
           font-size:16px;
            font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
                 right:63rem;
                 border-right: 1px solid;
       }
           p.text3 {
           position:fixed;
          bottom:23rem; 
          text-align:center; 
         width:160px;
           font-size:16px;
            font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
               right:39rem;
                 border-right: 1px solid;
       }
           p.text4 {
           position:fixed;
         right: 16rem; 
          bottom:23rem; 
          text-align:center; 
        width:160px;
           font-size:16px;
            font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

       }
               p.text5 {
           position:fixed;
         left:17rem;
          bottom:23rem; 
          text-align:center; 
           width:160px;
           font-size:16px;
            font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
             border-right: 1px solid;



       }
    </style>
    </head>   

<body>
    <img src="Logo-Trans.png" class="logo" >

    <div class="toptext"> 
    <h9> GET A QUOTE</h9>
    <h10> RETRIEVE A QUOTE</h10>
    <h7>NEED HELP OR ADVICE?CALL US <br style>  </h7>
        <h8> 0800 0481804</h8>
        </div>



<img src="nav.png" class="column"> 






<div class="container1">

  <div class="row">


<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="pt-inner-wrap">     
    <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-4x"></i>

    <h4 class="pt-title">Mobiles &amp Smartphones</h4>
    <figcaption>How many would you like to insure?</figcaption>


    <img src="10.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;"> <figcaption>Total Value when new</figcaption>

    <img src="10000.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;"> <figcaption>Would you like instant replacement?<i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right;1rem; color:grey" ></i></figcaption>

    <img src="replacement.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;"> 

</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="pt-inner-wrap">     
    <img src="tablet.png" style="height:50px;">

    <h4 class="pt-title">iPad's &amp Tablets</h4>
        <figcaption>How many would you like to insure?</figcaption>

    <img src="10.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;"> <figcaption>Total Value when new</figcaption>

    <img src="10000.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;"> <figcaption>Would you like instant replacement?<i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="right;1rem; color:grey"></i></figcaption>

    <img src="replacement.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;"> 

</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4" >
    <div class="pt-inner-wrap" style="border-right: 0px  ">     
    <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-4x"></i>
    <h4 class="pt-title">Laptops &amp Macbooks</h4>
  <figcaption>How many would you like to insure?</figcaption>
    <img src="10.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;">
<figcaption>Select the value range for the device(s)</figcaption>
    <img src="2000.png" width="100px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;"> <figcaption>OR</figcaption>
    <h6 class="pt-title"></h6>
    <img src="multiple.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;" onclick="window.open(this.src)">

</div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>          


 <!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




      <div class="box1"> 


<div> <img src="laptop.png" class="laptop"> </div>


<div class="bottomtext">Please enter a figure for the number of individual laptops/macbooks that you would like to insure in each price range.  Where you dont want cover with a particular price range, please leave bank.</div>




<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="">

        <div class="col-xs-2" id="p1">0</div>

           <p class=Text1>Up to £500 <br>How many would you like to insure?</p>

        <div class="col-xs-2 col-half-offset" id="p2">0</div>
         <div style="position:absolute; left:10rem;">
          <p class=Text2>Up to £500 <br>How many would you like to insure?</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-half-offset" id="p3">0</div>
         <div style="position:absolute; left:10rem;">
             <p class=Text3>Up to £500 <br>How many would you like to insure?</p> </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-half-offset" id="p4">0</div>
         <div style="position:absolute; left:10rem;">
             <p class=Text4>Up to £500 <br>How many would you like to insure?</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-half-offset" id="p5">0</div>
         <div style="position:absolute; left:10rem;">
             <p class=Text5>Up to £500 <br>How many would you like to insure?</p></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>

  </div>       





    <div class="footer">

       <div class="center-bottom">

<a class="my-button" title="Relevant Title" href="#">BACK</a>
<a class="my-button" title="Relevant Title" href="#">NEXT</a>

</div>

  <p> © Insync Insurance Solutions Ltd 2016 All rights reserved. Mobiru is a trading style of Insync Insurance Solutions Ltd which is authorised and regulated by the Financial Conduct Authority. Our registered office is Midland House, 2 Poole Road, Bournemouth, Dorset BH2 5QY and we are registered in England under company number 08810662. Should you have cause to complain, and you are not satisfied with our response to your complaint, you may be able to refer it to the Financial Ombudsman Service, which can be contacted as follows: The Financial Ombudsman Service Exchange Tower, London, E14 9SR | <br>Tel: 0800 023 4567 or 0300 123 9 123 | www.financial-ombudsman.org.uk | Terms of Business </p>
          <img src="Logo-Trans.png" class="logo1">
</div>


    </body>





</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in the future I would suggest that you copy over only the relevant code to the problem you're facing. Dumping all the HTML, CSS, and JS into a single block like that, much of it not being pertinent to the problem you're trying to solve, makes it difficult for others to slog through.

Now, since your already including jQuery (though you need to include it in your `<head>` tag), you might as well just use some CSS and the `.toggleClass()` function included with it.

Below is some code that displays it in action, as yours was a bit cluttered to display a concise concept. You basically need to execute the `.toggleClass()` function on the desired element (the laptop/mac section) when the button is clicked. If you want it to look smoother, you'll want to look into the `.hide()` and `.show()` functions. Documentation can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

```js
$( "#toggleBtn" ).click(function() {
  $( ".laptops" ).toggleClass( "show" );
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
.laptops {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #32CE87;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <button id="toggleBtn">Show and Hide</button>
      </div>
      <div class="laptops">
        <p>
        The content you want to show and hide. Here is the mac/laptop section.<br>
        More stuff about laptops.<br>
        Event more content if you wanted it.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you just want an element to appear when another element is clicked, you can easily do so using js. I normally handle the visiblity in css, and add a class to make the element appear.

HTML:

```
<div class="toggler">
Click me
</div>
<div class="element">
Hello
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.element{
       opacity:0;
    }
.element.show{
       opacity:1;
}
```

JS:

```
var elementToClick = document.querySelector(".toggler");
var elementToShow = document.querySelector(".element");

if(elementToClick){
    elementToClick.addEventListener("click", showElement)
}

function showElement(){
    elementToShow.classList.add("show");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L3r43pg0/

Comment: Thanks @olep, I just tired that on my webpage. Unfortunatly it didn't work would you be able to edit my js fiddle? and try it?

Comment: togglBtn is an id, so it needs to be # instead of .. Also you need to wait for the dom to load, hence the $(document).ready function.
https://jsfiddle.net/2j4b4bdn/4/

Comment: I just tried the updated jsfiddle you sent me and it doesnt work :/

Comment: It adds the class like it should. You just need to change the css to make it do what you want when the "active" class is added.

Comment: Oh right, Do you know the type of css I need to add?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. The jsfiddle is missing some images, so it's hard to see the end result. But you should just style the box like you want it to be, and then add "display:none;" when you're done.